# why is every haskell type lifted (ie, occupied by _|_)?

Tags: haskell

Why is every non-primitive haskell data type lifted (ie, occupied by `_|_`)?

I've heard one reason is the existence and semantics of `seq` but I've never seen a full explanation why that makes them all be occupied by `_|_` - ie why none of them may be unoccupied by `_|_`.

In addition to that, what other reasons are there?

Comment: the best answer would be a link to a thesis or alternative nonstrict haskell-like programming language where the reasons have been eliminated and a sound system is described.

Comment: For the whole story, read Winskel's book on programming language semantics, where he defines eager and lazy denotational semantics for HOFL (a simple functional language). Lazy semantics lifts domains more than its eager variant -- that's the whole point of it. Haskell decided to be lazy instead of eager -- this is a design choice, and could have been done otherwise.

Comment: thanks chi, I'll add it to my list of books to study, but will it include the succinct list I'm looking for? The succinct list and a statement that the book explains how each item forces type lifting would be a great answer!

Comment: I don't think you'll find a list of "reasons", since it's a design choice rather than something mandatory. In the book you see a definition for eager and lazy semantics, so you can see what happens if you lift domains (lazy) or not (eager). Haskell chose to be lazy, Ocaml chose to be eager.

Comment: @chi: "no reason, the feature to allow it could be added" would be a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a sense in which it's not true that all types are inhabited by `_|_`.  For example, given:

```
newtype Foo = Foo Int
```

The least element of this type is `Foo _|_`.  This is significant because pattern matching on `Foo` never fails, even for `undefined`.  This is still a least element of the type, and indeed all Haskell types must have a least element.  The reason is that even if you didn't have `undefined` and `error` in the standard library, you still need to have a value for `let x = x in x`, which is a term built from pretty fundamental language constructs, and that inhabits all types.

Comment: That's very interesting, I wondered about them, but I didn't check because `fix id :: GHC.Prim.Int#` is an invalid expression due to `fix id` not unifying with unlifted types and I was sure it would unify with a newtype (and it does now that I check).

Comment: If only newtypes could have more than one field... how close we are to sanity

Comment: not quite all types: (let x = x in x) :: Int# ----- Couldn't match a lifted type with an unlifted type ....

Comment: I edited the question to qualify it to "data type" instead of just "type" but you deserve positive karma for your response.

Comment: The fact that `fix id :: SomeUnliftedType` is an error because `fix id` is only for lifted types is going to be a key part of the answer to this question but it will still lead to a "Well, why doesn't it work for unlifted types if it can work for newtypes?"

Comment: I've selected this answer because it shows that there's no reason for it to be how it seems to be (by pointing out that it's not like that).

Answer (score 5):

It's a direct consequence of laziness and general recursion. All* values may be unevaluated expressions in the presence of laziness. All unevaluated expressions might diverge in the presence of general recursion. When evaluation diverges, the value is bottom.

*There are contexts where you might have a value that's known to be evaluated already, such as coming from pattern matching on a constructor with a strict field. But for every (lifted) type there are ways to generate unevaluated values of that type. `undefined :: a` is one such way.

Comment: There are lazy languages without bottom. It is a consequence of laziness and general recursion.

Comment: @Rein True, I'll add that in.

Comment: I noticed that we always know a 2-tuple's constructor is `(,)`, so `fix id :: (a,b)` doesn't have to be `_|_` it can be `(_|_,_|_)` which means 2-tuples don't have to be occupied by bottom, so I think there must be a 3rd factor to conjoin with those two to explain it. In this case I already wonder if it's modularity that is added to force 2-tuples to be occupied by `_|_`.

Comment: I'm not sure that really changes much, you could say that just makes `(_|_,_|_)` the new bottom for products: `_|_ = (_|_, _|_)`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, that's exactly the thrust of my question, why isn't it so - but I've phrased it to get a complete answer that can be methodically examined without all the red-herrings in a full book, and rather than the incomplete status-quo answers we mostly have. To be a duplicate, this requested list would have to be available and that would be grand.

Comment: An answer as clear cut as what you're asking for sounds like it could be at least a research paper worth of work...

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, perhaps someone has read or written that research paper and a link to it would be a good answer.

Comment: @Carl, See Chris Smith's answer where he points out that newtypes are not occupied by `_|_` but they can still be used in general recursion with laziness.

Comment: `fix id :: a` is a valid value of type `(a,b)` and its implementation cannot produce a tuple of any kind. Perhaps the 3rd factor you are looking for is parametricity. A language with typecase could, perhaps, behave as you suggest.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, thanks, how does parametricity prevent `fix id :: (a,b)` from being `(undefined::a,undefined::b)` ie, preventing unlifted `(a,b)`?

Comment: It doesn't. As I said, it prevents `(undefined, undefined)` from being a value of type `forall a. a`. You can't define `bottom :: a; bottom = (undefined, undefined)`.

Comment: if tuples were unlifted then you could define leastDefined :: a; leastDefined = let x = x in x. Then leastDefined :: (a,b) would equal (leastDefined,leastDefined)